# Como utilizar gif no Android?

Tags: android

Já tentei usar GIF no `ImageView` , porém não funciona , tem algum jeito de fazer com que o Android aceite imagens GIF?

Comment: https://github.com/Cutta/GifView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem algumas formas possíveis de fazer isso. Uma delas, que seria a forma fácil, é você importar um módulo já pronto, como por exemplo [android-gif-drawable](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable). Mesmo já estando na documentação, veja abaixo uma exemplo de uso:

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/soud"
        android:layout_weight="0.60" />

</LinearLayout>
```